# Publish WAR file to Maven Repo using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, war

I have a Parent Module Gradle project which contains sub-projects. One of those sub-projects is a web application. When I'm publishing to the maven repo, it is published as ONLY the jar file despite having both jar and war created locally

Parent file Gradle settings:

```
configurations {
        integTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
        integTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

allprojects {
    ext {
        springVersion = "4.0.4.RELEASE"
    }

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { 
    sourceCompatibility = "1.6"
    targetCompatibility = "1.6" 
}
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'


repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://.../mirror/"
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.blah'
            version '1.2'
            from components.java
        }
    } 

    repositories {  
        maven {
            credentials {
                username ""
                password ""
            }

            if(project.version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')) {
                url "http://.../snapshots/"
            } else {
                url "http:/.../internal/"
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.8.2'   
}
}
```

And the web application gradle

```
apply plugin: 'war'

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

war {
    baseName = 'portal-web'
}

dependencies {
compile(project(":portal-web-breadcrumb"))
compile(project(":portal-entity"))

compile(group: 'commons-beanutils', name: 'commons-beanutils', version: '20030211.134440')
compile(group: 'commons-digester', name: 'commons-digester', version: '2.1')
compile(group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-api', version: '3.0.1')
compile(group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-core', version: '3.0.1')
compile(group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-jsp', version: '3.0.1')
compile(group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.5')
compile(group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'log4j-over-slf4j', version: '1.7.5')
compile(group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2')
compile(group: 'taglibs', name: 'standard', version: '1.1.2')
compile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: "$springVersion")
compile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: "$springVersion")
compile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: "$springVersion")  
compile(group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.15') {
    exclude group: 'javax.mail', module: 'mail'
    exclude group: 'javax.jms', module: 'jms'
    exclude group: 'com.sun.jdmk', module: 'jmxtools'
    exclude group: 'com.sun.jmx', module: 'jmxri'
}   

providedCompile('javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0')
providedCompile(group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jsp-api', version: '2.0')
providedCompile(group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '6.0')
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I haven't done this before, but does 'from components.java' mean? may change to 'from components.web' or 'from components.war'?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For publishing a War, configure the `MavenPublication` with `from components.web`.

Answer (score 11):

Add this under your publishing:

```
publications {
    mavenWeb(MavenPublication) {
        from components.web
    }
}
```

Comment: `Invalid publication 'mavenWeb': groupId cannot be empty`

Comment: you must define in your build.gradle the group and version properties so that it is published following an organized directory structure. For example: group = 'your.company'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'